# How to efficiently load complete @ManyToMany self joined table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, lazy-loading

I have a simple "region" table with a relation to itself modeled through a join table. A region may be part of several super-regions and also may contain many sub-regions. My region class holds references to both, its super-regions and its sub-regions. Both sets may be empty. Altogether I have a couple of thousand entries and they will not change much over time. My problem is the efficient loading of the entire table via hibernate HQL into memory. So far, hibernate tries to create queries to get the super-regions for each region, although I specified lazy loading. I guess I overlook some configuration or parameter.

The class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region", catalog = "things")
public class Region extends Thing{

  private Set<Region> subRegions = new HashSet<>();
  private Set<Region> superRegions = new HashSet<>();

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name="region_region",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_id")}
  )
  public Set<Region> getSubRegions(){
    return this.subRegions;
  };

  public void setSubRegions(Set<Region> subRegions) {
    this.subRegions = subRegions;
  }

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="subRegions")
  public Set<Region> getSuperRegions(){
    return this.superRegions;
  }

  public void setSuperRegions(Set<Region> superRegions) {
    this.superRegions = superRegions;
  }
```

The code where I try to load all regions via HQL:

```
Query regionQ = session.createQuery("select region " 
     + "from Region region").setReadOnly(true); 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Region> allRegions = regionQ.list();
```

Why does that result in so many queries (I suspec N+1, although I did not count), not only one?

What do i have to do, to quickly load my table into memory. Clearly one single database query would be sufficient.

Comment: Does it make any difference without `setReadOnly`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic No differenece I am afraid.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with your mappings, but everything works as expected, both region collections are lazy. Could you post the SQLs being generated?

Comment: it works for me too, but it takes forever to load...

Comment: So, are the collections lazy or not? Do you have one query or more? If more, then are they related to many-to-many relations? Or they are related to something in the `Thing` inherited by `Region`? I think you'll have to post more details, otherwise we won't be of much help to you. :)